# Incorrect Promoter and Benefactor badge descriptions

Tags: support, bounties, bounty-badges

I've done two bounties for my own questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782714/gcc-vs-ms-c-compiler-for-maintaining-api-backwards-binary-compatibility) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816829/looking-for-a-semi-free-license)). If you go to my [Promoter](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/220/promoter?userid=241776) badge home page then you see a description:

> **Promoter** First bounty you offered on your own question.
>
> developer earned this badge **1 time**

I suppose it to be a bug because it should either list only the first bounty and doesn't show the number of times or list all the bounties. I think the description should be corrected. "Earned this badge 1 time" text should be removed for badges you can only get once.

Comment: Promoter and Benefactor are, like Editor or Mortarboard, one-time only badges. [Editor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor?userid=146126) shows the same effect... curiously, [Mortarboard](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/50/mortarboard?userid=146126) does not.

Comment: @Grace: Mortarboard does not because it can't show a question which earned you the badge, unlike Editor.

Comment: The implied feature request in this question is also in *[Unclear wording on pages of post- and tag-associated badges that can be earned once](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99366)* (although the fix seems to be broken at the time of writing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can only earn that badge once. So it is correct in saying you only earned it one time.** It's not showing only the number of times you earned it, it's showing *what question you earned it for*.

Compare to [the editor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor?userid=75801). The badge page is showing what question was the first one I edited, and thus, what question earned me the badge.

Comment: Combining your point on that, I can understand this a bit more. Thanks, @There!

Comment: I understand the correctness. I mean that it looks like "developer earned this badge N times", where N=1

Comment: Which is correct, you did earn it once time. You can't earnnit more than once.