# Unclear wording on pages of post- and tag-associated badges that can be earned once

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

The heading "**$name earned this badge 1 time**" is used for badges associated with specific posts or tags. To me, this suggests that the badge could be awarded multiple times, but it's also used for badges that can't be.

> [image]
>                                                              <sup>*Has Jeff only created a single tag?*</sup>

In these cases it would be clearer to just use something like "**$name earned this badge**".

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple and effective - your suggestion has been committed and will roll out with the next build.

Comment: Seems [it's back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208768/regression-of-jeff-atwood-earned-this-badge-1-time).