# Don't display how many times the badge was earned for badges earned at max once

Tags: feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarify wording on badge page for post-associated badges that you can only earn once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99366/clarify-wording-on-badge-page-for-post-associated-badges-that-you-can-only-earn)

If you look e.g. on [Tumbleweed badge of someone](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=1059316) you see:

> Jinka earned this badge 1 time

which is quite confusing because it suggests that the badge could have been earned more times. But this badge can be earned only once. So my suggestion would be to change that message  to something like:

- Jinka earned this badge
- Jinka earned this badge (awarded only once)
- ...

Also the question is whether it lists all the questions for which this badge applies or only the first one.

Comment: You might want to edit the title to "Don't display how many times the badge was earned for badges that can only be earned once", since it seems pretty useful to see 'earned 1 time' when it is actually possible to earn it multiple times.

Comment: @Aberrant, of course I meant it so, I just formulated it confusingly :-)Thanks.