# Regression of "Jeff Atwood earned this badge 1 time"

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, plurals, regression

There seems to be a regression of *[Unclear wording on pages of post- and tag-associated badges that can be earned once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99366)* (confusing text for one-time-rewarded badges):

[image: Current output of the taxonomist badge reward page for a user (on Stack Overflow)]

That is, it is expected to display "earned this badge".

Is this deliberate?

Comment: OK, I don't know about the title... It could be more descriptive and less catchy.

Comment: At least he didn't earn it 1 *times*...

Comment: I believe you're meant to add a fews Es a single K and maybe spell the word broken in a new and interesting way. For instance, your title might become _"EEEEEEEK! Earned this badge one time is b0rk'n again"_ - or something.

Comment: The whole badges page went through a major change as part of moving it into the new help center, no official annoucement except some [comments here on this old request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72744/152859), but most some bug fixes in the old code have been overwritten/didn't make it over to the new code.

Comment: Guess what we just internationalized? (not my fault)

Comment: This has nothing to do with [Jeff Atwood's Big-S](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) (*Pluralization Bug*, from *[The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19478)*) as these badges ***can not*** be awarded more than once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aah, lost in translation..

This *bug* was (re-)introduced as we cleaned out all the pluralization - or rather singularization - logic from our views. Watch for build numbers `DATE.1678` on meta and `DATE.1175` on sites.

Comment: Wow that was a quick deploy!

Comment: *This bug has been fixed two time(s)*

Comment: I’ve said it before and I’ll say it again: not using *once* and *twice* where it makes sense to do so doesn’t make sense not to do so. :(