# Please fix the pluralization in "earned this badge 1 times."

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, plurals

The page showing how many times a user has earned a specific badge, e.g. [this one](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/badges/67/quorum?userid=10273), has a [pluralization bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236746/295232); it says

> earned this badge 1 times.

[image: screenshot of page showing number of times a badge was won by a user]

Apparently, [this bug has been fixed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208768/295232) but recent(?) changes have brought it back.

Comment: You earned it so well that a singular count didn't seem a sufficient accolade. Plus, it *is* a quorum . . .

Comment: In case an answer is not posted: this was just tagged [tag:status-completed].

Comment: Thanks Adam for fixing it and Sonic for the ping; as you knew, I didn't receive a global inbox notification from the edit.

Comment: Ha, I was gonna write a quick answer and got sidetracked. My bad :)

Comment: Haha, Its bit funny to see that mistake.

Comment: @bad_coder ... there's still 8 hours to go before midnight, and they're the most active hours. You're sure you need these 15 points right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed, *time* is now written in singular; as shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of page showing number of times a badge was won by a user]