# The return of: Regression of "Jeff Atwood earned this badge 1 time"

Tags: bug, badges, regression

Badges that can only be earned once and once only have, *once again*, the confusing and unclear text:

> ...earned this badge 1 time.

When the expected text should read:

> earned this badge.

I'm not sure if this a new bug or the same one addressed by the accepted answer to [Regression of "Jeff Atwood earned this badge 1 time"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208768/regression-of-jeff-atwood-earned-this-badge-1-time) from November 2013 which says:

> This *bug* was (re-)introduced as we cleaned out all the pluralization - or rather singularization - logic from our views. Watch for build numbers `DATE.1678` on meta and `DATE.1175` on sites.

It seems that the above expected text was first suggested in July 2011 in the question [Unclear wording on pages of post- and tag-associated badges that can be earned once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99366/unclear-wording-on-pages-of-post-and-tag-associated-badges-that-can-be-earned-o), with the accepted answer saying:

> Simple and effective - your suggestion has been committed and will roll out with the next build.
> So has it been fixed and come back, or did it never go away?

I'm on an Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64 if it's relevant.

Comment: Regression - Stack Exchange earned this badge two times.

Comment: @RobertColumbia you must mean Stack Exchange earned this badge two time.